# .htaccess - Pretend that subfolder is Home

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an url (domain.com/games/) and Google decides to rank it higher as my home/root (domain.com).

Because home and /games are more or less redundant I'd like to show the content of /games without having it in the url and simply dump my original home content.

But all urls located in /games, like /games/metro-exodus should still contain /games/ in the url.

Is this possible with a solution via htaccess or is there no way around coding?

Comment: It is unclear what you actually mean by "But all urls located in /games, like /games/metro-exodus should still contain /games/ in the url."... Does that mean you want requests to URLs with a `/games` to still work or that this should be required in your application or whatever you have?

Comment: I want domain.com/games/* still to work like it is right now

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the http server's rewriting module and enable the interpretation of dynamic configuration files, if you want to use those, by means of the `AllowOverride` directive (see the documentation for how to do that).

Then this simple rule set should point you into the right direction, though you probably need to adjust it a bit for your specific situation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/games/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /games/$1 [END,QSA]
```

This will internally map all requests *without* a `/games/` prefix to that "subfolder". So you don't have to move anything, you just need to *remove* the physical files from the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of the server side file system, obviously except the `/games` folder.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).